# When will TCP/IP version 6 replace version 4?

Tags: networking, tcp

Since ~1999 everyone has been saying that TCP/IP v6 will replace v4 within then next couple of years. When might the change actually happen and what will be the implications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one can answer that question.
Valid answers may be anything from "any day now" to "never". What do you expect people to say?
IpV6 is actually gaining pretty good traction if you bother to take a look at Googles graphs and the number of AAAA hosts being published in the global DNS. And all mainstream operating systems (Windows, OS X, Linux, FreeBSD) support it out-of-the-box.
What more do you want? You cannot get any guarantees or (realistic) promises.